# How to change the same title of X-Y axis and formatin in many graphs at once using VBA?

Tags: vba

I want to change the same title of X-Y axis and format in many graphs at once using VBA.

I made code like below.

If I have 3 graphs, to change the second graph with the same X-Y axis titles and format, I copy and paste this code and change from ChartObjects(1) to ChartObjects(2), and also to change third graph, I also copy and paste this code again, and change as ChartObjects(3).

However, if I have 100 graphs, it seems impossible to copy and paste same codes  100 times, and change each ChartObjects.

Are there any methods to change X-Y axis titles in many graphs more easily?

Many thanks,

```
Sub axis() 
 Dim xytitle As chart 
 Set xytitle = Worksheets("graph").ChartObjects(1).chart 
 With xytitle.axes(xlCategory)
    .HasTitle = True 
    .AxisTitle.Text = "Treatment" 
    .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 11 
  .AxisTitle.Font.Bold = False
 End With 
  With xytitle.axes(xlValue) 
    .HasTitle = True 
    .AxisTitle.Text = "Grain weight" 
    .MaximumScale = 60 
    .MajorUnit = 10 
    .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 11 
    .AxisTitle.Font.Bold = False
 End With 

 End Sub
```

Comment: `For i = 1 to 100: Set xytitle = Worksheets("graph").ChartObjects(1).chart: Next i`

Comment: Thank you Tim!! I figured it out!! Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution!! Thank you:)

```
Sub axis()

 Dim xytitle As Chart
 
 Dim i As Integer
 
 For i = 1 To 4
 
 Set xytitle = Worksheets("test").ChartObjects(i).Chart
 
 With xytitle.Axes(xlCategory)
    .HasTitle = True
    .AxisTitle.Text = "Treatment"
    .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 11
    .AxisTitle.Font.Bold = False
    
 End With
 
  With xytitle.Axes(xlValue)
    .HasTitle = True
    .AxisTitle.Text = "Grain weight"
    .MaximumScale = 60
    .MajorUnit = 10
    .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 11
    .AxisTitle.Font.Bold = False
    
 End With
 
 Next
 
 End Sub
```